# React Native scroll to refresh is not working properly with pagination

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native please bear with me. I currently have a flatlist in my react native project which fetch's posts from my backend using an api. I have success implemented pagination on my backend and in my app when i scroll to the end it adds the newly fetched posts to the bottom of the current posts shown.

My problem is when i scroll to refresh, i only want the posts of page 0 to get shown.

What is happening is the posts on page 0 get added to the bottom of the posts instead of showing these posts only.

So for example, when i load my app, posts on page 0 get rendered and when i scroll to refresh instead of just showing posts on page 0, the posts on page 0 get added to the bottom of the posts on page 0 and therefore i get an error that id is duplicated.

The required action i am trying to obtain is when i scroll to refresh i just want the posts on page 0 to show.

Here is my code:

```
function PostsScreen({ navigation }) {
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
 const [error, setError] = useState(false);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const loadPosts = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const response = await postsApi.getPosts(page);
  setLoading(false);

  if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

  setError(false);
  setPosts([...posts,...response.data]);
 };

 const[page,setPage]=useState(0);

 useEffect(() => {
 loadPosts(page);
 }, [page]);

const handleLoadMore = ()=>{
console.log('loadmore')
setPage(page+1);
}

 const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

 return (
 <>
  <ActivityIndicator visible={loading} />
  <Screen style={styles.screen}>
    <FlatList
      data={posts} // to have all the data
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
        <Card
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subTitle}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, {post:item,index})}
        />
      )}
      refreshing={refreshing}
      onRefresh={() => {
        loadPosts(0); // I think the problem is here.//
        setPage(0);
      }}
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      initialNumToRender={10}
    />
  </Screen>
</> 
);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry can you rewrite your question. it's hard to understand. You want page 1?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial hi, my first page is page 0, what i want is when i scroll to refresh i just want to render page 0. my code currently when i scroll to refresh it adds page 0 to the array of pages rendered. is that a better explanation or should i rewrite my question?

Comment: can you try out the given code in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, I believe you want to implement pagination in your application and you have that in your code as well. Now, when you try refreshing your list, you just want to set the list to the initial 10 items. if so,

```
function PostsScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const loadPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await postsApi.getPosts(page);
    setLoading(false);
    if (refreshing)
      setRefreshing(false);
    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
    setError(false);
    if (page == 0)
      setPosts(response.data)
    else
      setPosts([...posts, ...response.data]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    loadPosts();
  }, [page]);

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  const onRefresh = () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    setPage(0);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={loading} />
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <FlatList
          data={posts}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <Card
              title={item.title}
              subTitle={item.subTitle}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, { post: item, index })}
            />
          )}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={onRefresh}
          onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
          keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
        />
      </Screen>
    </>
  );
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: this solution worked, thank you. I have a question do i need setRefreshing(true) in onRefresh function?

Comment: We are using the refreshing prop on flatlist, if you don't set it to true, you will no longer see the activity indicator on top of the list as you pull down. This is basically to give a visual impact to the user that data is being loaded in the background. You can read more about it at https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onrefresh

Comment: since i already have an activity indicator       <ActivityIndicator visible={loading} />
this already shows that data is being loaded

Comment: Yes. This one is more like a refresh control component. In android, if you pull down on this list, you can see an activity indicator being dragged from the top of the screen like what we see in this image https://i2.wp.com/angularscript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Pull-To-Refresh-For-Angular-Material.png?w=438&ssl=1. If this is not required, you can of course remove this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const loadPosts = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const response = await postsApi.getPosts(page);
  setLoading(false);

  if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

  setError(false);
  if(page=== 0){
     setPosts(response.data);
  }else{
  setPosts([...posts,...response.data]);
  }
 };


//...

onRefresh={() => {
        setPage(0);
        loadPosts(); // loadPosts takes no argument. 
      }
   }


//...

const handleLoadMore = ()=>{
    console.log('loadmore')
    setPage(page+1);
    loadPosts();
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried the code above and it works when i scroll to load more then refresh the posts on page 0 only get rendered but when i try to add a new post and then refresh i does not work.

Comment: please try using updated ```handleLoadMore()``` function

Comment: still not working properly, i will try to explain what is happening. the maximum number of posts on a page is 10, when i load my app, the first 10 posts get rendered then when i scroll to load more the next 10 posts get rendered. When i refresh the first 10 posts get rendered which is correct. now when i add a new post and try to refresh it shows 20 posts instead of just 10 posts.

Comment: the function is working perfectly, you just have to slice the elements rendered in a flat list to show the page you are on. in FlatList try using ```data: {posts.slice(page*10)}```

Comment: when i added data: {posts.slice(page)} when i tried loading more it went to straight to page 10

Comment: the problem about duplication of page 0 element, and original question and its resolved, I wish I had access to your flatlist implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225272/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-kd12345).